# LESS in Web Compiler for Visual Studio 2019 stopped to work

Tags: visual-studio, less, visual-studio-2019

It worked for years.
Yesterday for no reason (?) I'm not able to compile LESS files any more.
I tried to

- reinstall the Web Compiler extension,
- reinstall Web Essentials 2019 extension,
- reinstall the whole Visual Studio 2019 for 3 times,
- start a new project from scratch

I do not know if some automatic update happened under the hoods, but basically, every time I try to compile a LESS file I get:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompiler1.12.394\node_modules\less\bin\lessc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For VS2017 and VS2019:

- Uninstall the Web Compiler extension
- Delete* the directory `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompiler1.12.394`
- Install Web Compiler

I do not know why the "lessc" file disappeared.

* From cmd.exe:

```
rd /S %LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\WebCompiler1.12.394
```

From a PowerShell prompt:

```
rm -r $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Temp\WebCompiler1.12.394
```

---

How I found the solution: I attempted to re-create the .vsix file from the GitHub repository for the Web Compiler extension so that I could get the lessc file; I had installed Node.js and all its associated gubbins. Trying to use the node_modules.7z generated by build.cmd in the Web Compiler files didn't work in the end because there are several deprecated things in it - I ended up with the error described in [3.10: Breaks IE Compat Option](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3446). So I thought: oh dear, it is all broken, why not just delete the directory and try the install again?

Comment: I discovered that the 

C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompiler1.12.394\node_modules\less

has inside less files than expected, almost all sub folders are empty.

The only workaround I found, was to install Visual Studio (and extensions) on a clean PC and copy and paste all the files from the same aftermentioned folder.

It's not an elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: @Igor You're welcome :) It was perhaps 3 or 4 weeks since I last used Web Compiler, so I don't know when it broke. I suspect that that installer checks only for the presence of directories and not their content, or maybe it fails for files without a file extension, and it looks like the uninstaller doesn't completely uninstall.

Comment: I was able to fix this by only deleting the temp WebCompiler folder, and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Followed the steps from the Accepted answer. Uninstalled in VS, deleted the folder in the Temp directory, installed the extension.

I had a strange merge conflict that afterwards left me unable to compile and throwing the error from the question. Normally restarting VS or rebooting would fix minor stuff like this. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompiler1.12.394` folder and ran the compilation from Task Runner Explorer which recreated the folder without having to reinstall Web Compiler.

Maybe it is related to also having the BuildWebCompiler 1.12.405 NuGet package installed in the project.

Comment: Good thought, per the documentation it appears the Nuget Package is used in the Build Process: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler#compile-on-build--ci-support  Looks like Mads has abandoned this project to some extend.

Comment: I reverted back to version 1.12.394 of that Nuget Package and still had to go thru the install/uninstall to reset the extension.

Comment: I had two folders starting with 'WebCompiler' in there. Removing them both resolved the issue. Probably because I had used two versions of the extension and also the nuget package and they got confused with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix a similar problem with a "node-sass" file missing from the Web Compiler (although the entire bin folder was empty) by performing the following actions:

- close Visual Studio 2019
- delete the C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompiler1.12.394 folder
- restart Visual Studio.

When I restarted VS, the folder was recreated with all the necessary files back where they needed to be.

When I ran into the issue I had just came back to work after taking a little over a week off. At least for me, I think a program on my computer that automatically cleans up unused temp files may have been the culprit.